# Different buttons size

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-linearlayout

I'm quite new to Android, and I'm getting different sizes when I deploy my app to my smarthphone.

Here goes the screenshots:

**Android Studio Preview:**

[image]

**Smartphone screenshot:**
[image]

Please note the "/" button is smaller than anothers.

Here goes the problem:

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

This padding is truncating my last button, but why the android didn't divide the screen space among all buttons, considering the last button not really truncated, we can see the "/" centralized.

So how can I fit my buttons in the screen?

I almost forgot, here goes my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtResultado" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNumero1"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="Digite"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <!-- <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNumero2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="Digite"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSoma"
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="somar"/>

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubtrair"
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="subtrair"/>

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMultiplicar"
            android:text="*"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="multiplicar"/>

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDividir"
            android:text="/"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="dividir" />

        </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnResultado"
        android:text="="
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="resultado" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your second LinearLayout which included buttons

```
android:weightSum="4"
```

after that add this lines to each button:

```
 android:layout_weight="1"
```

These lines divide your Linearlayout 4  equal parts. And the each button fill the part of linearLayout.

Comment: @guisantogui No need for `android:weightSum="4"`.

Comment: @Vikram it works without `android:weightSum="4"` Thanks for the improvement